# Mongoose: virtual properties that depend on other virtual properties

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In mongoose, is it possible to have a virtual property that depends on another virtual property? For example:
If I have the properties `squaresAmnt`, `trianglesAmnt`, `appleAmnt`, and `pearAmnt` (all of type Number) and then create two virtual properties:

```
mySchema.virtual('totalShapes').get(function() {
  return this.squaresAmnt + this.trianglesAmnt;
});

mySchema.virtual('totalFruit').get(function() {
  return this.appleAmnt + this.pearAmnt;
});
```

Is it possible to create a 3rd virtual property `total` using the sum of `totalShapes + totalFruit` instead of the 4 properties on their own? For my very specific use case, I'd like to avoid the later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can refer to them with `this.` eg. `this.totalShapes`.

One thing to be careful of - if the person writing the query uses $select the fields your virtuals rely on might not exist; fields not returned by the query aren’t available to the virtuals. So be defensive and check for needed fields in your virtual implementations.